# Put A Silverlight App on HTML page

Tags: silverlight, embed

I am so new to silverlight. First I must ask a basic and fundamental question, Is it possible to put a SL app on a web page without any server behind it?

And after that, If yes :D, How can I put my SL app on a HTML page without any server.
I've tried object tag but nothing displayed (just a blank silverlight box).
I think it must be important to say, My XAP file is uploaded on another domain.

Answer (score 1):

There might be one of several issues here.

Firstly, yes you can embed Silverlight in HTML. If you create a Web project when you create your Silverlight project you'll get two test pages, one .aspx the other .html. It looks like this (well there's some script as well):

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:100%">
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
      <param name="source" value="ClientBin/SilverlightApplication1.xap"/>
      <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
      <param name="background" value="white" />
      <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="3.0.40818.0" />
      <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
      <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=3.0.40818.0" style="text-decoration:none">
          <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=108181" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
      </a>
    </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
</form>
```

Secondly, your Silverlight app should really live on the same server as your web site. If you move it into `ClientBin` (for example) then it should work. Though [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/9a573e34-b4ec-45eb-ab16-22e65cd09b53) seems to indicate that as long as your server can see the XAP file it should work. [This thread](http://forums.silverlight.net/p/101955/340407.aspx) indicates that you need to edit the `AppManifest.xml` file to add the following:

```
 <Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007/deployment"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
ExternalCallersFromCrossDomain="ScriptableOnly">
```

NOTE: I've not tried either of these.

Thirdly, you need to make sure that the Silverlight client runtime is installed.

Comment: When i put it on the same server it works fine. so there is no way to use xap files from other servers or domains?

Comment: @uni - you *might* be able to do it with a crossdomain policy file. I'm looking into that now.